# Change Virtualenv save location

Tags: python, django, terminal, virtualenv

I just set up a virtualenv, but I can only access it from the virtualenv-1.9.1 folder which is in my downloads folder (I'm on a mac).

[image]

How do I move this virtualenv to my project folder?

Info:
both venv and myvenv are virtualenv. I just need to move one though.

Thanks

Comment: In my experience it is better to just make the virtualenv in the folder itself, is there a reason you cannot do this?

Comment: I'm new to virtualenv. How do I build it in the folder? From my experiments (the reason there are multiple env) I can only build them in the virtual env folder in my downloads folder

Comment: @IdeoREX you can have as many environments as you wish, in any directory you wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could freeze your current env and get all the pacakges in it in a requirements file, then create a new virtualenv in the directory you desire.

```
cd your/package/directory
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install -r path/to/your/saved/requirements/file
```

Judging by your comments, I think it is important to understand that environments can be created anywhere on your filesystem you choose.  By using terminal and the `virtualenv` command you can create environments in any directory

Answer (score 0):

Virtualenv environments encode the original location of the venv in many files.

To fix this, using the same  virtualenv binary you created them with, run `virtualenv --relocatable <VENV_NAME>` to make them relocatable, then move the directories wherever you like. The `--relocatable` option is documented as "experimental" so using the frozen requirements method from dm03514's answer might be safer.